# Vue router remove params from URL

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a route set up like below. The idea is that if a user clicks a referral link then the key is stored. In the future if the user navigates to the path `/store` the same component is used and the referral link will be pulled from storage.

Do I need a route for both `/store` and `/store/:referralKey` or is there a way to do this with one route?

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/shop/:referralKey',
            name: 'shop',
            component: () => import('./views/Shop'),
            meta: {
                public: true
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: If you add `path: '/shop/:referralKey?', then it will make `referralKey` optional. Check and confirm

Comment: Glad to hear!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `?` after the Dynamic params and `vue-router` will make it optional.

```
path: '/shop/:referralKey?'
```

Hope this helps!